# Serialize multiple InMemoryUploadedFile using ListField : Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-uploads

How can I serialize multiple [**`InMemoryUploadedFile`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile) using [**`serializers.ListField()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) ??

---

**code snippet**

```
#views.py
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        altered_request_data = request.data.copy()
        in_memory_upload_files_list = [value for value in request.FILES.values()]
        altered_request_data['files'] = in_memory_upload_files_list
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=altered_request_data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=201)
    else:
        qs = Post.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

#serilizers.py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField(), write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Post
```

**current response**

```
{
    "files": {
        "0": [
            "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you does not need it, because you call `save` just process the files in the save and all be fine.

Comment: the given response is the validation error and it raised before calling the `save()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was lies in this line,

```
altered_request_data['files'] = in_memory_upload_files_list
```

here the **`altered_request_data`** is a [**`QueryDict`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) object, so if we assign anything to it will call the [**`__setitem__()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__setitem__) method

```
In [6]: from django.http import QueryDict                                                                                                                                                                          

In [7]: qd = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&c=3',mutable=True)                                                                                                                                                                 

In [8]: qd                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[8]: <QueryDict: {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': ['3']}>

In [9]: my_list = [i for i in range(10)]                                                                                                                                                                           

In [10]: my_list                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[10]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [11]: qd['foo']=my_list                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [12]: qd                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[12]: <QueryDict: {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': ['3'], 'foo': [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]}>
```

See that? **`qd['foo']`** become a ***list of list***. That is, anything assigning to a **`QueryDict`** will be stored inside a `list` object.

### So, what's the solution??

`QueryDict` class has a method [**`QueryDict.setlist`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.setlist) will do the job

```
In [15]: qd__new                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[15]: 

In [16]: qd__new = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&c=3',mutable=True)                                                                                                                                                           

In [17]: qd__new                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[17]: <QueryDict: {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': ['3']}>

In [18]: my_list                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[18]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [19]: qd__new.setlist('foo_new',my_list)                                                                                                                                                                        

In [20]: qd__new                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[20]: <QueryDict: {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': ['3'], 'foo_new': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}>
```

### code snippet

## views.py

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        altered_request_data = request.data.copy()
        in_memory_upload_files_list = [value for value in request.FILES.dict().values()]

        altered_request_data.setlist('files', in_memory_upload_files_list)

        serializer = PostSerializer(data=altered_request_data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=201)
    else:
        qs = Post.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should use `getlist` method of `FILES` that will give you List of Files.**

```
in_memory_upload_files_list = request.FILES.getlist('<file field name>')
altered_request_data['files'] = in_memory_upload_files_list
serializer = PostSerializer(data=altered_request_data)
```

**Here `<file field name>` will be name file field on which you upload file.**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Comment: I'm uploading the files as this - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFn6F.png) and I am not interested to specify the names in `getlist()` method, because I'm uploading multiple files

Comment: you are using key "file" just put "file" replace in <file field name>
In you snapshot you mentioned file_1, file_2 means postman uploading images based on "file" field name.

Comment: Without key you can't get anything for FILES, POST and GET. you will always get dictionary in these method. so that always need keys to access it

Comment: What if I want to upload **`n`** number of files? and the DRF side is not aware of which `key` (such as `file_1`,`file_2`,`file_3` ..etc)is used to send those `n` files. That's why I used the ***`.values()`*** method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645410/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-django-rest-framework try this way

Comment: that too didn't help me. Anyway I found a solution :)

Comment: @JPG Please share the solution :(