# How to upload multiple files with django rest api?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to upload multiple images with django rest api. I followed the following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645410/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-django-rest-framework). But when I select one or more files and try to send them to the server as form data, I get the following error message:

`AttributeError at /api/photo/ 'bytes' object has no attribute 'name'`

**Model:**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='audio_stories/')
```

**Serializer:**

```
class FileListSerializer ( serializers.Serializer ) :
    image = serializers.ListField(
                child=serializers.FileField( max_length=100000,
                                         allow_empty_file=False,
                                        use_url=False )
                                )
    def create(self, validated_data):
        image=validated_data.pop('image')
        for img in image:
            photo=Photo.objects.create(image=img,**validated_data)
        return photo
```

**View:**

```
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FileListSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    queryset=Photo.objects.all()
```

**URL**

```
router.register('api/photo', PhotoViewSet, 'photocreate')
```

I dont know how to approach the error, as i have nothing in my code that relates to "name"?

Comment: How are you uploading the photos?

Comment: @Paul via Postman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seemed to be in the serializer. I had to set the `use_url=True`.

**Serializer:**

```
class FileListSerializer ( serializers.Serializer ) :
    image = serializers.ListField(
                child=serializers.FileField( max_length=100000,
                                         allow_empty_file=False,
                                        use_url=True )
                                )
    def create(self, validated_data):
        image=validated_data.pop('image')
        for img in image:
            photo=Photo.objects.create(image=img,**validated_data)
        return photo
```

**Extended Answer**

The above answer works but produces an large null array.
In order to make the code work I had to seperate my two models in Story and Story_Media. Each instance of Story Media contains a single image and provides a FK to the Story.

```
class Story (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} Story'

class Story_Media (models.Model):
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name = 'story_media', related_query_name = 'story_media')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='story_media/',  null=True, validators=[validate_file_extension_image])
    isTitlePicture = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} Media'
```

In my serializer, a new Sotry_Media instance is created for each image included in the incoming data. In my case, it was necessary to create a story even if no images were uploaded, so the two conditions are included.

```
# Story  Serializer_Media_Serializer
class Story_Media_Serializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Story_Media
        fields =  ('id','isTitlePicture', 'file',)


# Story  Serializer
class StoryCreateUpdateSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    story_media = Story_Media_Serializer(many=True, required = False)


    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields =  ('title','description', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        current_user = self.context["request"].user

        # Story  contains images
        if 'story_media' in validated_data:
            story_media = validated_data.pop('story_media')
            story_instance = Story.objects.create(author=current_user, **validated_data)
            for img in story_media:
                Story_Media.objects.create(**img, story=story_instance)
            return story_instance

        # Story  is not containing images
        if 'story_media'not in validated_data:
            story_instance = Story.objects.create(author=current_user, **validated_data)
            return story_instance
```

```
class StoryCreateUpdateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StoryCreateUpdateSerializer

    http_method_names = ['post','delete','put','patch', 'head']

    queryset = Story.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated, PostOwnerPermssion
    ]
```

[image: API Post]

Comment: I was stuck on the same issue . Your approach helped me a lot. I tried out your way , its working fine but while uploading files through postman , it is showing a huge null array . Do you know why it is happening ?

Comment: yes, i encountered the same problem with the null ary and solved it. let me share my code when i am back at my pc.

Comment: can you help me up ? Thanks

Comment: @Mitesh i extended my answer.

Comment: can you please update your viewset ? thanks

Comment: @mitesh also have  a look at the postman settings.  Feel free to up vote the question and / or answer in case it helps you.

Comment: I am going to try this one tomorrow , thanks for the help , man .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider implementing like i did which is working for me

**Model**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='hotel_photos')
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(
        Hotels, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Photos'

    def __str__(self):
        """Prints the name of the Photo"""
        return f'{self.hotel} photos'
```

**Serializer**

```
class PhotoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = (
            "image",
            "hotel",
        )
```

**Helper function**

```
def modify_input_for_multiple_files(hotel, image):
    dict = {}
    dict['hotel'] = hotel
    dict['image'] = image
    return dict
```

**Views.py**

```
class PhotoUploadView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    This API view handles multiple images upload form
    It will also display images for specific hotel
    """
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    # http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head']

    def get(self, request):
        all_images = Photo.objects.all()
        permission_classes = (IsAdminOrOwner,)
        serializer_class = PhotoSerializer(all_images, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        hotel = request.data.get('hotel')
        images = dict((request.data).lists())['image']
        flag = 1
        arr = []
        for img_name in images:
            modified_data = modify_input_for_multiple_files(hotel, img_name)
            file_serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=modified_data)

            if file_serializer.is_valid():
                file_serializer.save()
                arr.append(file_serializer.data)
            else:
                flag = 0

        if flag == 1:
            return Response(arr, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(arr, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Hope this can help you or anyone stuck. In case of any question shoot it please

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to add multiple files that are strored in a file list. It appears to me that your code assumes for each file an individual form?

Comment: The code assumes that you are adding photos to another model such as a blog photos, user photos etc. But you can easily customize the code to just upload photos without necessarily tying to another model