# I can't upload multiple files in django running in docker

Tags: docker, file, nginx, django-rest-framework, multiple-file-upload

I followed the example: [How to upload multiple files with django rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793086/how-to-upload-multiple-files-with-django-rest-api) The solution work in localhost, but when i upload to nginx server running in a container docker, the nginx return a error 400, i can't more details because i'm not getting log, my nginx configuration it is like this:

```
upstream api {
    server neworleansenglishcourse.com.br:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name neworleansenglishcourse.com.br www.neworleansenglishcourse.com.br;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 8000M;
        client_body_buffer_size 8000M;
        client_body_timeout 120;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        client_max_body_size 8000M;
        client_body_buffer_size 8000M;
        client_body_timeout 120;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    location /complementos/ {
        client_max_body_size 8000M;
        client_body_buffer_size 8000M;
        client_body_timeout 120;
    }

}
```

My docker compose it is like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    backend:
        build:
            context: ./api
        command: gunicorn plataformaingles.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks: 
            - production-network
    frontend:
        build:
            context: ./front
        volumes:
            - front_build:/front/build
        networks: 
            - production-network
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/nginx-setup.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - front_build:/usr/share/nginx/html
        depends_on:
            - backend
            - frontend
        networks: 
            - production-network    
volumes:
    front_build:             
networks: 
    production-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late for you, but I had the same problem today that my multiple=True file field only worked on localhost.
I noticed that I had slightly different Django installations locally (3.2.16) and in docker (3.2.20).
I solved it by downgrading the Django version in my docker container to 3.2.16.