# How can an array of object be posted using Django DRF if this objects contain a file and other data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to post an array of objects via the Django DRF. The array comes from my React JS frontend and contains a file and other data:

```
[{"image":"file object", "title_picture":"false"}, {"image":"file object", "title_picture":"true"},{"image":"file object", "title_picture":"false"}}
```

I get the image via a FileFild and the title_picture via a CharField, with the code below ([following this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645410/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-django-rest-framework)) I can post a image list, but I lose the title_picture i.e., i get something like that `[{"image":"file object",}, {"image":"file object",}, {"image":"file object"}]`

```
###Model###
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_stories/')
    title_picture = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='some_value')

###Serializer###
class FileListSerializer (serializers.Serializer):
        image = serializers.ListField(
                    child=serializers.FileField( max_length=1000,
                                        allow_empty_file=False,
                                        )
                                )
        def create(self, validated_data):
            image=validated_data.pop('image')
            for img in image:
                photo=Photo.objects.create(image=img)
            return photo

###View###
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FileListSerializer
    
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    http_method_names = ['post', 'head']

    queryset=Photo.objects.all()
```

**Basically my question is how to post an array (list) of objects if these objects contain a file and some other data.**

Comment: Is there a reason you don't explicitly specify the field `title_picture` in your `FileListSerializer`? I think you can just add it there and use that information as well in `validated_data`.

Comment: @physicalattraction thansk for your response. My `validated_data` only includes the image but not the `title_picture`. If i print the `validated_data` it only contains the file `{'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 3.jpeg (image/jpeg)>]}` so i can not access the addtional data. I assume it gets blocked by the pre filtering of the file filed.

Comment: With your current implementation you indeed have no field `title_picture`. What you need is to specify that in your serializer: `title_picture = serializers.CharField(...)`

Comment: than you now i can access the title_picture. I will post the answer when i have it.