# DRF Uploading to aws s3 multiple files(more than 1)

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

**My Headers from Postman**[image]- I have endpoint which successfully upload to AWS s3 bucket image but when I try to upload more than 1 file, It upload last one. How can I fix that?[image]

**My view:**

```
class MediaViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Media.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MediaSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

**My serializers:**

```
class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Media
        fields = ('uploaded_at', 'upload')
```

**My Model:**

```
class Media(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    upload = models.FileField(storage=MediaStorage())
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this but I think it should be handled by the browser via headers.

So [RFC 7587](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.3) says

> 4.3.  Multiple Files for One Form Field
>
> The form data for a form field might include multiple files.
>
> [RFC2388] suggested that multiple files for a single form field be
> transmitted using a nested "multipart/mixed" part.  This usage is deprecated.
>
> To match widely deployed implementations, multiple files MUST be
> sent    by supplying each file in a separate part but all with the
> same    "name" parameter.
>
> Receiving applications intended for wide applicability (e.g.,
> multipart/form-data parsing libraries) SHOULD also support the older
> method of supplying multiple files.

So I think you will just have to post with

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=something; name="file"
```

More about boundaries in [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) or [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data).

---

Can you list all the headers you send?

Ok, so your headers are correct. You have a few options.

1. This idea doesn't sound good. If possible, upload files one by one as POST should return 1 new entity.
2. Overwrite `create` method and when you initialize serializer pass `many=True` to it or create them one by one.
3. Create a separate view, something as `UploadMultipleFiles(GenericViewSet)` where you will have a total control over what's happening.
4. Or even `UploadMultipleFiles(CreateAPIView)`.

I think you should pick the 2nd option so something like this should work

```
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        uploaded_files = []

        for uploaded_file in request.FILES:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(upload=uploaded_file)
            serializer.is_valid(True)
            instance = self.perform_create(serializer)
            uploaded_files.append(instance)

        response_serializer = self.get_serializer(uploaded_files, many=True)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(response_serializer.data)
        return Response(response_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: yes I added picture with headers in my question

Comment: thanks! I changed request.DATA to request.POST cause of ***request.DATA` has been deprecated in favor of `request.data` since version 3.0***
and now got ```django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'upload'```
any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, maybe try `request.data` instead of `request.POST['upload']`. Either way, you need to inspect `request.data` and `request.POST` and you will find what you need in there :)

Comment: Updated answer. Maybe this will work Or `request.data['files']`

Comment: nope( `TypeError: string indices must be integers` in your updated answer

Comment: Then I run out of ideas

Comment: me too ) Is it even possible?)

Comment: Yes, I think so. One of the solutions above should work but I can't try it right now

Comment: I know, maybe try with `MultiPartParser` or `FileUploadParser` parser https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

Comment: Found the solution on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645410/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-django-rest-framework :)